# Adding more than one graph to mainPanel in Shiny (R)

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to have multiple html outputs in my shiny App but it seems like it can only show one at a time.

My UI is:

```
# ui.R 

shinyUI(
mainPanel(

tableOutput("view"),
plotOutput("view2")

))
```

And my server is:

```
# server.R
library(googleVis)
library(RMySQL)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {



datasetInput <- reactive({

    "try2" = subset(try1, idCampaign == input$inputId)

})



output$view <- renderGvis({

gvisTable(datasetInput(),options=list(width=1000, height=270, col='blue'))

})

output$view2 <- renderGvis({

gvisScatterChart(datasetInput2())


})

})
```

Answer (score 0):

in the output to view2 you use `datasetInput2()` , this should be `datasetInput()`. Here `datasetInput()` just represents a dynamic version of a dataframe, you can use it in as many functions as you want, there is no need to index it.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively i think you can use the `tabsetPanel` to divide your main page into certain parts and assign output objects to each of your `tabPanel`.