# Shiny - multiple outputs to mainPanel

Tags: r, shiny

Shiny seems to only accept the final output of any provided to `mainPanel` in `ui.R`.  An [earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996434/adding-more-than-one-graph-to-mainpanel-in-shiny-r) raised this but reached no satisfactory solution.  The documentation for mainPanel suggests this should be possible:

> Description: Create a main panel containing output elements

The following code illustrates:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    plotInput <- reactive({
      list(plot = plot(1:10),
        txt = "My reactive title")
    })
    output$myplot <- renderPlot({ plotInput()$plot })
    output$txt <- renderText({ plotInput()$txt })
  }
)
```

**ui.R**

```
require(shiny)
pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Multiple outputs to mainPannel"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel({
    # only the last output works
    h1(textOutput("txt"))
    plotOutput("myplot")
    p("see what I mean?")
  })
)
```

Does anyone know if this is a bug, or how to work around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
  mainPanel(
    # only the last output works
    h1(textOutput("txt")),
    plotOutput("myplot"),
    p("see what I mean?")
  )
```

Comment: Don't be; the nasty nesting and the confusing error messages makes Shiny a happy debugging adventure (even if it's ingeniously designed).

Comment: Thanks.  By the way do you have any comment on the `plotInput()$plot` approach to delivering multiple outputs from `reactive()`?  I'd be interested to hear if there's a better method..